# VS2015 compiler error message "the name client.UseDefaultCredentials does not exist in the current context" for simple C# SMTP Code

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0

my search on the net always ended up with webclients or other clients than that for SMTP and was pointing me in an area of reference errors, which I couldn't resolve, as it does not seem to fit in my case, or I simply don't see the forrest for all the trees by now. Another hint of the order on UseDefaultCredentials didn't solve it either.

I have the following code, which I got from Stackoverflow and other tutorials on SMTP in C# which I intended to customize to my needs.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
namespace XXX
{
    class SendMessage
    {

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("test2@domain.com", "test@domain.com");
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com");

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        //
        //mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
        //mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
        //client.Send(mail);

    }
}
```

where things are "fuzzy" is the error I get from the compiler in VS2015, which states the name client.UseDefaultCredentials does not exist in the current context. The creation of the client does seem to work.
I was hoping to solve it by adding a using System.Net.Mail.SMTP; but that doesn't help.
I also get an invalid token '=' in class, struct,... but why?

Comment: You've just declared a class with a bunch of code statements in it. You need a method of some kind, a body to wrap your code statements. A class can have members (methods, fields, properties) but it can't have just... code. That belongs in a member with a scope.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I am so embarrassed, you are absolutely correct. As I said forrest for the trees...
thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can't write code directly into your class you need a function or a method for it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
namespace XXX
{
    class SendMessage
    {
        public void sendEmailMessage(){
           MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("test2@domain.com", "test@domain.com");
           SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com");

           client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
           client.Port = 25;
           client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
           //
           //mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
           //mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
           //client.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```